# Number whose sum of digits with same exponent is the same number

Tags: c++

First of all I want to sorry, because I hade similar question last week. I didn't understood it correctly and when I edited that topic, seems that noone saw it. But I have to finish this programme tommorrow as it's a hometask.

Here is the programme in C++:

"User enter two numbers. Programme takes it as the interval in which it checks all the numbers. If there's a number in interval which all digit's sum of SAME exponent is that number, then programme shows it."

For example, I enter 100 and 200. In this interval there's 153.

153 = 1^3 + 5^3 + 3^3 (1+125+27)

Programme shows 153.

But NOT 28. Because 28 = 2^1 + 2^3 (2+8=10, not 28)

And so on.

```
cin >> n;
cin >> m;
    for (int i=n; i<=m; i++)
    {
        for (int k=n; k<=i; k++)
        {
                a = n % 10; //for example, I enter 153, then a=3
                f = n /= 10; //f=15
                b = f % 10;  //b=5
                f = f /= 10; //f=1
                c = f % 10; //c=1
                f = f /= 10;
                d = f % 10;

                for (int j=1; j<=5; j++) //checks the exponent
                {
                    a = a * a;
                    b = b * b;
                    c = c * c;
                    d = d * d;
                    if (a + b + c + d == n)
                    {
                        cout << n << endl;
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

I defined integers a,b,c,d, so this code could handle numbers with up to 4 digits. 
Code is simple, but I can't see the problem.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I am closing this as a duplicate as you should have edited your question and not post an answer to your own question with what you need.

Comment: I note at least two main errors: the second loop (for k=1 to n), what does it mean? Second, in the innermost loop (for j=1 to 5), you multiply a = a * a at each loop, that is the first round a = 3 * 3. But the second round a = 9 * 9. You lost a = 9 * 3, and so on.

Comment: @NathanOliver, well, I wouldn't have made a new question without editing the old. Which I did. But it seems that this way old question doesn't get attention I need and there's no help incoming.
Anyway, Thank You all for letting know my mistakes, I will try to do my best.

Answer (score 1):

You keep squaring `a` here:

```
a = a * a
```

So you'll be checking with a squared, a to the fourth power, ....